# Compiling classes at runtime with spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, compilation, classloader

I have two gradle projects:

- A java project that defines some business entities.
- A java Spring Boot API Rest project that is dependent of the first projec

The API Rest project exposes a `POST` endpoint that does a runtime compilation of some Java Code.

This Java code extends a class whose parent is defined in the business project.

The code compilation is done via `InMemoryJavaCompiler` at https://github.com/trung/InMemoryJavaCompiler.

Depending on how the application is launched, two cases arise:

- When launching and debugging the API Rest with **`IntelliJ` works fine**. The code is compiled and can be executed.
- When launching and debugging the API Rest with **`java -jar` it does not work**. The jar is packaged with the `bootJar` task. Java executble is from a JDK

Does not work precisely means that the classes defined in the business project are not seen by the `InMemoryJavaCompiler` classloader at runtime, therefore the compilation fails.

Example stack trace

```
2019-01-19 10:33:50.955 ERROR 1636 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mdkt.compiler.CompilationException: Unable to compile the source
[kind=ERROR, line=1, message=package com.foo.entities does not exist]
[kind=ERROR, line=1, message=cannot find symbol
  symbol: class BaseClass]
[kind=ERROR, line=1, message=cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Entity
  location: class com.foo.myClass]
[kind=ERROR, line=1, message=method does not override or implement a method from a supertype]] with root cause

org.mdkt.compiler.CompilationException: Unable to compile the source
[kind=ERROR, line=1, message=package package com.foo.entities does not exist]
[kind=ERROR, line=1, message=cannot find symbol
  symbol: class BaseClass]
[kind=ERROR, line=1, message=cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Entity
  location: class com.foo.myClass]
[kind=ERROR, line=1, message=method does not override or implement a method from a supertype]
        at org.mdkt.compiler.InMemoryJavaCompiler.compileAll(InMemoryJavaCompiler.java:106) ~[InMemoryJavaCompiler-1.3.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.mdkt.compiler.InMemoryJavaCompiler.compile(InMemoryJavaCompiler.java:126) ~[InMemoryJavaCompiler-1.3.0.jar!/:na]
```

The Spring Boot version is `2.1.2` and java is version 8

The code i'm trying to compile is this, in a single line, but here formatted to improved readibility

```
package com.foo; 
import com.foo.entities.Entity; 
public class myClass extends BaseClass {
    @Override public void evaluate(Entity entity) { 
        System.out.println(entity); 
    } 
}
```

How may I make this API Rest work when packaged and distributed as a`jar`??

Kind regards.

Comment: Are you running  `java -jar` with JDK or JRE?

Comment: Edited OP, is a JDK